# Approach for running OpenTelemetry agent

Tags: instrumentation, telemetry, open-telemetry

I understand OTEL is still evolving at the time of this writing, but I'm trying to work out a good approach for running the OTEL agent in our containerized ecosystem in Kubernetes to collect logs, metrics, & traces and exporting to our telemetry vendor of choice - I won't say what telemetry vendor we're using as we're looking to deliver a vendor agnostic approach.

At this stage my thinking is that we should run the OTEL agent as a side-car container. The main reason for this is because of service metrics exposed in Prometheus/OpenMetrics format at `/metrics`. If we were to run the OTEL agent as a daemonset or on the underlying hosts, we'd probably have to constantly update the OTEL config as services are added/removed/rescheduled and AFAIK there's no auto-discovery mechanism. If we run OTEL agent as a side-car we can assume communication over the local pod network and just use prometheus receiver scraping from localhost as follows:

```
receivers:
  # ...
  prometheus:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
        - job_name: 'otel-collector'
          scrape_interval: 5s
          static_configs:
            - targets: ['localhost:5001']
```

For logs we'd set up some kind of shared (ephemeral) volume between the service and the OTEL side-car, so that we can use the file receiver e.g.

```
receivers:
  # ...
  filelog:
    include: [ /var/log/*.txt ]
```

For traces we'd configure the OpenTelemetry auto-instrumentation libraries for [.NET](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/USAGE.md) & [Java](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation) (depending on whether the service is .NET Core or Java respectively) as part of the container build i.e. in the Dockerfile. We'd configure this to use something like OTLP|Zipkin|Jaeger exporter to the OTEL agent running as a side-car in the local pod network that's configured with appropriate receivers e.g. OTLP|Zipkin|Jaeger respectively.

For all of the above, we'd export to something like Kafka (or AWS Kinesis, or Azure Event Hubs - depending on the cloud provider we're using) primarily as a streaming layer, but also as an abstraction layer between our ecosystem & the telemetry vendor. The telemetry vendor can then ingest from stream. If we ever need to get logs, metrics, traces to a different vendor/solution, we could do this without really needing to touch anything in our ecosystem.

Does this sound like a good approach?